# Who is the Resourceful Rat and what does he do?

Tags: enter-the-gungeon

In Enter the Gungeon when you leave an item in a room except hearts this weird rat dude takes it I've tried shooting him but of course he had a shield and disappeared. But when I left after I shot him he wouldn't come back so I walked away but when I came back later the item was gone with a rude note. Who is he? And does he do anything in the game?

Answer (score 2):

The Resourceful Rat is an invulnerable NPC that picks up most items that you leave lying on the floor.

Once you find an item, you normally have a chance to pick it up. If you decide you don't want the item, the Resourceful Rat will come and steal the item while you're not in the room. It takes him about 3-5 seconds to take the item (he leaves a mean note behind when he does, which you can read for some humor). If you shoot him during this time, he will swear ("&$*#@!") and disappear again. Now he will not show up until you are at least *two* rooms away. If you still manage to get back to the first room (by teleporting back, for example) and shoot him while he's picking up the item, he'll disappear again - however, he'll keep trying to steal the item again once you're far enough away.

In the end, there is no good way to prevent the Resourceful Rat from stealing your dropped items. However, there is a upside to this NPC - he will not steal hearts or keys that you leave on the floor.

Additionally, if you take an elevator shortcut to floor 3+, the Resourceful Rat will be standing near the elevator exit in a ridiculous costume and he'll offer you some free guns.

Comment: It sounds like the Rat will also be a boss in the upcoming "Gungeons and Draguns" DLC, but I don't have concrete details. I'll update the answer when I do.